# Getting Class Path entry xxx.jar in "/content/XXXApp.ear/APP-INF/lib/ESAPI-1.4.4.jar" does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference

Tags: jboss, classpath

23:58:02,447 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "XXXApp.ear"
23:58:05,119 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry commons-configuration-1.5.jar in "/content/XXXApp.ear/APP-INF/lib/ESAPI-1.4.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:58:05,119 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry commons-collections-3.2.jar in "/content/XXXApp.ear/APP-INF/lib/ESAPI-1.4.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:58:05,120 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry commons-lang-2.3.jar in "/content/XXXApp.ear/APP-INF/lib/ESAPI-1.4.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

Can anyone tell me where the actual problem may be ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning that means that jar ESAPI-1.4.4.jar contains a MANIFEST file that has a property Class-Path ponting to several jars that can't be found:

- commons-configuration-1.5.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.jar
- commons-lang-2.3.jar

This means these jars are either not present or they have a different name. Check if the jars are present, if that is the case this warning can be safely ignored.